# Understanding how binding a StringVar to an tkinter widget works with events

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

When I call a function from a tkinter widget event I need to add a second parameter in the definition line of the function. Like onChange(self,event) or onChange(self,test). "event" and "test" being the second parameter.

Like:

```
def onChange(self, test): 
    print('Content is: ', test.widget.get())
    #this also works, but only when having "test" or any other other second parameter name in the def line:
    print('Content is: ', self.var.get())
```

My problem as a beginner in Python/Tkinter is that I do not understand this second parameter and why it is needed. Do anyone have a good explaination of this and/or references to other sources to improve my understanding?

I also would like to understand why this function without the second parameter does not work.

```
def onChange(self):
    print('Content is: ', self.var.get())
```

A small sample program:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class GUI:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tk.Tk()
        self.create_widgets()

#   The following function works with "test" or any other second parameter name in the def line:     
    def onChange(self, test): 
         print('Content is: ', test.widget.get())
         #this also works, but only when having "test" or any other other second parameter name in the def line:
         print('Content is: ', self.var.get())         

##  The following function does not work: 
#    def onChange(self):
#         print('Content is: ', self.var.get())   


    def create_widgets(self):
        # Makes an Entry widget:
        self.string_entry = ttk.Entry(self.window,width=30)
        self.string_entry.grid(row=0,column=0)

        self.var = tk.StringVar()
        self.var.set('Change me and press enter!')

        self.string_entry["textvariable"]=self.var
        self.string_entry.bind('<Key-Return>', self.onChange)

program = GUI()
program.window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you check the indentation of your code? Are the functions supposed to be part of the class?

Comment: The indention is ok on my side. Yes, the function is supposed to be part of the class. But I am a beginner and appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Ok. As written, the two functions onChange and create_widgets are not part of the GUI class. They need to be indented one level (so they're level with the `__init__` method).

Comment: My program indention is ok. The wrong indention is caused by copy paste into the stackoverflow web interface. I have now tried to correct how the code appears above. Sorry about this, this is my first post on this forum.

Comment: No problem. I thought that might be the case but didn't want to edit it in case that was how your code was.

Answer (score 0):

You are allready adding variables that are "extra".
the self variable that you add in the call signature is also a variable that gets filled by the system (python )when calling a class method.
In the same way when an callback is being called by tkinter by the an event, tkinter adds extra variables, in this case the event.

The event variable contains extra information on why the callback is called, this to enable the same callback to be able to handle several different events.

The page http://effbot.org/ is pretty old and is mainly describing Python2 code but it is in most cases update enough to learn about tkinter and how it works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Admittedly, it still is a bit unclear to me why the “test” parameter (second parameter) is needed and what it is. I found this approach on internet and used it successfully in a larger program. It however annoys me that I do not understand the mechanism.

Comment: I think that the test parameter would better be named event, but as with the self variable you can call it foo if you like.
So its something that is passed on from tkinter.
If you want to explore it try the construct print(dir(test)) to see what it acctually contains

Answer (score 0):

The Tk framework that calls your function, passes a variable to your callback function (as well as the `self` variable all methods are called with). When your second method is called it can't accept the second argument so throws a TypeError.

There is more information about the bind methods [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm).

If you don't care about the argument, you can use the varargs syntax to ignore anything that's passed in.

```
def onChange(self, *_):
    print('Content is: ', self.var.get())
```

Comment: Thanks-this was useful. 
I think the best practice is to use the argument name "event" like suggested by Svavelsyra.